# What is the importance of keysigning?

Tags: android, security

I have begun to make android app's and I want to make it into an APK file. When doing so I checked the android docs and they talked about jarsigner and zipalign. I was wondering what these do and why I need them. Also why do you need a public and private key and what do they do? Why are they so dangerous if someone gets them?

Answer (score 1):

The key stores are users to make sure that you are the only person to publish updates for your app. When you sign your app and publish it to Google play, you need to make sure that you back up your key store because they are not recreateable, and if you lose your key store then you can't publish updates. Jarsigner is just a tool that you use to 'sign' your app, and zipalign is an optimisation of your app that has nothing to do with your keystore(as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

If you **sign** your files (or any other data, like WLAN data), no-one is able to modify them (as they are not able to resign the file). So these signed files are telling everyone your were the one making them.

The **public** key is used to verify you are the one who signed the file or data. It is not usable to sign the file though (only for checking).

This is all great (and safe), except if they have your **private** key, then they are also able to sign files while pretending they are you. So they would be able to put a nasty virus in your application without anyone noticing. Hence it would be a disaster when you lose your private key(s).

Public and private keys (and encryption techniques using them) are not android specific, they are used for all secure communication, data storage, emails, etc.

For more information, check [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and/or look up 'public/private key' on the Internet.

Comment: This answer is more relevant to general security on the web, and not as much to Android dev I think.  Good info though, thanks.

Comment: I deliberately kept it generic, as it applies on all situations (including Android specific) and I understood from the question that the OP does not know (much) about this subject in general.

Answer (score 0):

You sign your app to prove you are the only publisher of the app.

You really don't need to worry about the specifics of the key, and if you are using the standard Android Dev Tools (ADT), there is a wizard to walk you through the creation of a key you an use to publish your app

To export with the tools:
Right-click your project --> Android Tools --> Export Signed App
Hit next, then the second screen will allow you to "Create a new key".  Select this and you can create everything you need.

You will need this key to publish (even if you don't put it in the Play Market, you still need to sign an App to run it on any device).

If you do publish to the Play Market, and lose your keystore (or password) - you will not be able to update that app.  Ever, there is nothing you can do about it.  Keep it somewhere save.

Someone would need both the keystore file, and the password to sign your app, (and your Play Market password), so the key alone isn't that important (obviously, you need to keep all this stuff safe).